# List all subpages hierarchically based on the currently viewed page, top ancestor levels included

Tags: plugins

Based on the current page, I'm listing the links of all pages which belongs to the parent ancestor. However when I'm accessing a grandchild, the top parent page will gone from the links hierarchy. This is what I have tried:

```
<?php
// display the sub pages from the current page item
if($post->post_parent) {
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
    $titlenamer = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
    $permalink = get_permalink($post->post_parent);
} else {
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
    $titlenamer = get_the_title($post->ID);
    $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
}
if ($children) {
    ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>"><?php echo $titlenamer; ?></a></h2>
    <ul>
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

What I'd like is to have listed all the pages with subpages hierarchically based on the currently viewed page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$parent = array_reverse(get_post_ancestors($post->ID));
$titlenamer = get_the_title($parent[0]);
$permalink = get_permalink($parent[0]);
if ($post->post_parent) {
    $ancestors=get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
    $root=count($ancestors)-1;
    $parent = $ancestors[$root];
} else {
    $parent = $post->ID;
}
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=". $parent ."&echo=0");
if ($children) { ?>
<h2><a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>"><?php echo $titlenamer; ?></a></h2>
<ul id="subnav">
    <?php echo $children; ?>
</ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

This will work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_post_ancestors()` ([codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors)) to get an array of all the ancestors id's, so if I understand you correctly you might want to use

```
child_of=".end(get_post_ancestors($post->ID))
```

instead of

```
child_of=".$post->post_parent
```

where `end()` ([php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)) gives you the last element of the array.